# Convolutions Support.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convolution

It is known that:
$$
\operatorname{supp}(u *v) \subset \operatorname{supp}(u) + \operatorname{supp}(v)
$$
Where:
$$
\operatorname{supp}(u) = \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: u(x) \neq 0\}}
$$
And:
$$
(u*v)(x)=\int_\limits{\mathbb{R}^n} u(x-y)v(y) dy
$$
I need an example of two functions $u,v$ such that $u$ has compact support, but $u*v$ has no compact support. Does anyone know any examples of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u$ be any non-negative function with compact support which has the value $1$ on some open set. Let $v(x)=e^{-x^{2}}$. Then $(u*v)(x) >0$ for all $x$. So $u*v$ does not have compact support.

For an explicit example let $u(x)=1$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $0$ for $x \geq 1+\frac 1 n$as well as for $x \leq -\frac 1 n$, $u(x)=1+nx$ for $-\frac 1 n \leq x \leq 0$ and $u(x)=1-n(x-1)$ for $1 \leq x \leq 1+\frac 1 n$.

There is no such example where both $u$ and $v$ have compact support.  If $u$ has support $K$ and $v$ has support $H$ then $u*v$ vanishes on the complement of $K+H$. Since sum of two compact sets is compact it follows that $u*v$ has compact support.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any function of compact support $u$ (with non empty interior) such that 
$$
u \ge 1\quad \forall x\in \operatorname{int}(\operatorname{supp}(u))
$$
where $\operatorname{int}$ is the *[interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology))* operation.
Then by choosing
$$
v(x)= 
\begin{cases}
u(x) & x\in \operatorname{supp}(u)\\
e^{-\Vert x\Vert^2}& x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus \operatorname{supp}(u)
\end{cases}
$$
we have the required example, since the convolution is such that
$$
\begin{split}
u\ast v(x)&=\int\limits_{\Bbb R^n}u(x-y)v(y)\mathrm{d}y\\
&= \int\limits_{\operatorname{supp}(u)}u(x-y)u(y)\mathrm{d}y+\int\limits_{\Bbb R^n\setminus\operatorname{supp}(u)}\!\!u(x-y)e^{-\Vert y\Vert^2}\mathrm{d}y\\
&\ge \int\limits_{\operatorname{supp}(u)}\mathrm{d}y+ \int\limits_{\Bbb R^n\setminus\operatorname{supp}(u)}\!\!e^{-\Vert y\Vert^2}\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\operatorname{\mu}(\operatorname{supp}(u))+\!\!\!\int\limits_{\Bbb R^n\setminus\operatorname{supp}(u)}\!\!e^{-\Vert y\Vert^2}\mathrm{d}y>0\quad\forall x\in \Bbb R^n
\end{split}
$$
where $\mu(A)$ is the Lebesgue measure of the set $A$.

Comment: Little correction: There is u in place of v on line 7.

Comment: @RodolfoFerreiradeOliveira thank you very much for pointing it out. As you can see, the error was deeper: I forgot an entire part of the expression of $v(x)$. Without your observation and the subsequent correction, my answer would have been meaningless. Thanks!

Comment: I thank you! Your example helped me